# About Android talkback. I want to play audio file when item is focused

Tags: android, listview, listener, talkback

i am developing an album application for visually-impaired people.
I made custom list view to display list of photos.

What i want is playing audio file when each item is focused using Talkback(Android Accessibility service).

For example, when one of the item in custom list view is selected, I want to play specific audio file for that item, not simple TTS that just reads text.

Is there any way to do that?
Is there any listener that can handle this issue? like button click listener.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do something by clicking on list item. If you are using RecyclerView, in onCreateViewHolder you can use setOnClickListener for your view:

```
@Override
public YourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int 
viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.myview, 
parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    return new YourViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: Is this working for talkback?
I am sorry for abstract description. I want to find "Focused stated in Talkback" not click event in usual context(without accessibility service).